# How can I set a windows environment variable as part of a pipeline?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've got a yaml pipeline that needs to set (create if not there) a windows environment variable on a VM that is to be used by another program on the VM. How do I go about doing that?

I've tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432799/how-to-set-and-read-user-environment-variable-in-azure-devops-pipeline) (amongst other articles) but none of the answers worked. They either needed the .NET SDK installed or didn't fail but didn't create the variable. I get the impression this should be possible using powershell, so very similar to one of the answers in that question I tried this:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Set environment variables.
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_KEY;]$(TestSecret)"
```

Like I say, this doesn't fail, but when I check the VM environment variables 'MY_KEY' doesn't exist.

***UPDATE***

Following the suggestion below from Lee_Dailey I tried the following:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Set environment variables.
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | 
          [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MY_KEY", "$($env:TestSecret)", "Machine")
      env:
        TestSecret: $(TestSecret)
```

I also tried replacing the actual value of the key with just "testKey" rather than using a variable, as well as setting [Environment] rather than [System.Environment]. In all cases the pipeline ran without errors but no environment / system variable was created on the VM with the name MY_KEY.

I double checked it was running this on the right machine by writing the computer name to the console, so I know it's not somehow doing this on another machine.

Comment: take a look at `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` - that will set a env var that _can_ be visible machine-wide.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - I've tried your suggestion but unfortunately this still doesn't create the variable. If you have any other ideas please let me know.

Comment: i see that you got it working as needed. great! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one of my earlier attempts actually did work. However, the way I was checking the variables wasn't picking up on it (command prompt using 'set' to read them all, didn't restart the session). So I checked through the system settings GUI and found it was getting set after all. I ended up with this:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Set environment variables.
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | 
          [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MY_KEY", "$(TestSecret)", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```